# How to use Keydrown to move images across the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard

In a project that I am working on, a core functionality is to be able to move an image around an HTML5 Canvas element by using the WASD keys. Due to the nature of default keyboard behavior, I have decided to use the [Keydrown](http://jeremyckahn.github.io/keydrown/) library to move an image. Unfortunately, because I am not all that much of a seasoned and experienced programmer, this objective has proven to be a bit of a roadblock. Here is my current code:

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var xPos = -1320;
    var yPos = -495;
       ctx.beginPath()
       ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000"
       ctx.arc(400, 225, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI)
       ctx.stroke()
       ctx.fill()
    // Create the image object
    var background = new Image();
    
    // Add onload event handler
    background.onload = function () {
    // Done loading, now we can use the image
    ctx.drawImage(background, xPos, yPos);
    };
    
    function move(e){
    
    /*if(e.keyCode==68){
        xPos-=10;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==65){
        xPos+=10;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==87){
        yPos+=10;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==83){
        yPos-=10;
    }*/
    
    kd.D.down(function () {
     xPos-=10;
     console.log(xPos)
    })
    kd.A.down(function () {
     xPos+=10
    })
    kd.W.down(function () {
     yPos+=10
    })
    kd.P.down(function () {
     yPos-=10
     })
     kd.run(function () {
      kd.tick();
    })
    canvas.width=canvas.width;
    ctx.drawImage(background, xPos, yPos);
    
    }
    
    //document.onkeydown = move;
    
    background.src = "https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/8/1/8/399576-synthwave-wallpaper-3440x1440-screen.jpg";
```

```html
    <script src="https://jeremyckahn.github.io/keydrown/dist/keydrown.js"></script>

    <img id="wallpaper" width="3440" height="1440"
    src="https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/8/1/8/399576-synthwave-wallpaper-3440x1440-screen.jpg" alt="img" style="display:none;">
    
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="450"
    style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use `canvas.width = canvas.width`. Instead use something like `clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`.

To make something move using the keyboard, you have to do:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    xPos -= 10;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    xPos += 10;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    yPos += 10;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    yPos -= 10;
  }
});
```

What you missed is adding an event listener to the document to check if a key was pressed.

Hope this helps!